# get of Map<string,string> not a function in Angualr Testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

Angular testing throws 
`TypeError: _co.mapNumbers.get is not a function`
in the test running with Karma. Component works fine and code is like below:

In component I have declared:

```
export class A{
     mapNumbers:Map<string,string>;
     ngOnInit() {
       mapNumbers = JSONOBJECT[0] // Assignment of values works fine and also matches the type
}
```

In template:

```
<span>
          {{mapNumbers.get('24_HOURS_ASSISTANCE_PHONE_NUMBER')
            ) | translate
          }}
        </span>
```

It's nothing complex but seems it does not work for Karma, Do I need to do a special import for Map here?

Answer (score 1):

It's strange but seems like unless I use Map's set method direct assigning only works with the app but not unit testing:

```
arrayOutput = new Map();

arrayInput.foreach((value: string, key: string) => {
        this.arryOutput.set(key,value);  // Unit test fails unless assing the values through set method
    });
```